# Store data generated within nested loop in map or slice

Tags: php, go

I am coming from PHP background and trying to build small tool that would allow me to filter the list of keywords against the black list both supplied via CSV file. I managed to do that in PHP but it has some speed limitation. So I decided to try my powers with Golang. I have succeeded to open CSV file `fmt.Println` the contents of both keywords and blacklist, and managed to compare each of the keywords to each of the blacklists keyword. But the problem I face is that I can figure out how to build dynamic associative array something like that.

```
   function compareKeywords($keyword, $filters) {
        $matches = [];    
        foreach($filters as $filter) {
            $matches[] = strpos($keyword, $filter);
        }    
        $matches = array_filter($matches);    
        if(empty($matches)) {
            return $keyword
        }
    }
```

This function simply checks keyword against fully or partially matching the blacklisted keywords if it does not match the blacklisted keywords it returns this keyword and then adds it to CSV file.

I spent decent amount of time trying to create similar function in Golang but I struggle to mimic the associative array from PHP.

I came up with slightly different function which accepts keywords rather than single keyword as well as filters and uses nested loop.

```
func compare(keywords [][]string, filterKeywords [][]string) (keywordMap //no sure what type it should be) {
    matchFilters := make(map[string]string)
    keywordMap :=  make(map[string]string)

    for _, keyword := range keywords {
        for _, filter := range filterKeywords {
            if convStr(keyword) == convStr(filter) {
                // here i want to store matches filters 
            }
        }
    }

    //Check if matchFilters empty and return filtered keywordMap

    return

}
```

I know my code may look verbose and look a bit lame. But any advice into direction I should move would be very appreciated.

Comment: Could you list out a sample row from keywords and filter csv file? How do you intend to map keywords to filters?

Comment: I will have two files. List A, will contain 1 column
Keyword
------------------------
Keyword 1
Keyword 2
Thrase 1
Thrase 2

List B will contain blacklisted keyword as well with one column.
Keywords
-----------------------------------
Keyword
2


Each keyword from List A will be checked against each keyword from List B. Which should return array of matching values. The output of this filter should be Thrase 1 from List A. Because we have to rows with word Keyword and two rows with number 2, the only one that does not match is Thrase 1 keyword which should be returned.

Comment: I can use strings.Contain function to determin if any of List A keywords match the keywords from List B but I don't understand how to store that, in the form of associative array. In order to later populate List C with filtered keywords...

Comment: Here is my complete code so far https://play.golang.org/p/dmnxoOUrO6

Comment: Do you really need a map as a result? What would be a key and value pair of this map? Shouldn't the filtered keywords be only a list of keywords (an array or a slice)? Also, could you clarify exactly how `Therse 1` would be the output above?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know PHP, but as far as I understand from the PHP code the Go equivalent should be:

```
func compare(keyword string, filters map[string]struct{}) (string, error) {
    // value, ok := myMap[key]
    // this is Go syntax for checking the existance of a key in a map - check the ok variable.
    _, filterMatched := filters[keyword]
    if filterMatched {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf("keyword %s got filtered", keyword)
    }

    return keyword, nil
}
```

In other words you could just use the `map` type, but having a helper function that clears our intention is good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code with some optimizations, try it on the [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8q1HGgoyQT):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    filters := []string{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}
    fmt.Println(compareKeywords("a", filters)) // ""
    fmt.Println(compareKeywords("d", filters)) // "d"
}
func compareKeywords(keyword string, filters []string) string {
    for _, filter := range filters {
        if strings.Index(filter, keyword) >= 0 {
            return ""
        }
    }
    return keyword
}
```

output:

```
d
```

---

And see `strings.Index` Docs:

```
func Index(s, sep string) int
```

> Index returns the index of the first instance of sep in s, or -1 if sep is not present in s.